# bootstrap grid system col-xs-12 not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<header class="row">
  <div class="logo-box col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <img class="header-logo img-responsive" src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/udacity-content/rebrand/svg/logo.min.svg" alt="udacity logo" />
  </div>
  <div class="nametag col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <h1>SIYU WU</h1>
    <p class="personal-title">
      FRONT-END WEB DEVELOPER
    </p>
  </div>
</header>
```

The related style are shown below:

```
header {
  display: flex;
}
.logo-box {
  padding-top: 40px;
  height: 120px;
}

.header-logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 53px;
}

.nametag {
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

I'm using bootstrap's framework but it seems not working. The two div each take 50% width no matter the screen size. But if I remove the second div the 1st one will take 100% width at xs size screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bootstrap columns system depends on the `display` of the `.row` being `block`.

By changing it to `flex`, you've broken it. The children of flex elements have different rules for wrapping.